# Реализация Undo Redo в графическом редакторе.

Tags: delphi

Как можно реализовать `undo redo` в графическом редакторе 5-6 изменений.

Если можно, исходник (или кусочек кода).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда я писал графический редактор, то сделал это так. Возможно, немного запутанно получилось, этому коду полтора года точно есть. Этот код позволяет отменить 9 последних действий.

```
    // процедура добавления картинки в массив картинок
        procedure TGraphEditorForm.AddBitMap; // её я объявил в разделе private
        Var
          j: Byte;
        begin
          BitMap.Assign(ImagePicture.Picture.Bitmap); // BitMap - глобальный битмап
          If (Index>=10) Then // переменная index - целая, глобальная
            Begin
              For j:=0 To 8 Do BitMas[j].Assign(BitMas[j+1]);
              BitMas[9].Assign(BitMap); // добавляю в глобальный массив
              Index:=9;
            End
          Else BitMas[Index].Assign(BitMap);
        end;

      // это у меня обработчик действий, происходящих при отжатии кнопки мыши на рисунке  
        procedure TGraphEditorForm.ImageEditMouseUp(Sender: TObject;
          Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
        begin

 // тут у меня код, который рисует на нижнем Image, то, что было нарисовано на верхнем
// этот код я здесь приводить не стал

// если была нажата какая-нибудь из инструментальных кнопок, то
          If (((SpeedButtonPen.Down) Or (SpeedButtonBrush.Down) Or
            (SpeedButtonErase.Down) Or (SpeedButtonSpray.Down) Or
            (SpeedButtonFill.Down) Or (SpeedButtonFragment.Down) Or
            (SpeedButtonText.Down) Or (SpeedButtonLine.Down) Or
            (SpeedButtonRectangle.Down) Or (SpeedButtonEllipse.Down) Or
            (SpeedButtonRoundRect.Down) Or (SpeedButtonChord.Down) Or
            (SpeedButtonArc.Down) Or (SpeedButtonFigure.Down) Or
            (SpeedButtonRightTrigon.Down) Or (SpeedButtonRightPentagon.Down) Or
            (SpeedButtonRightHexagon.Down) Or (SpeedButtonRightHeptagon.Down) Or
            (SpeedButtonRightOctagon.Down) Or (SpeedButtonRightEnneagon.Down) Or
            (SpeedButtonStar3.Down) Or (SpeedButtonStar4.Down) Or
            (SpeedButtonStar5.Down) Or (SpeedButtonStar6.Down) Or
            ((SpeedButtonBezierCurve.Down) And (Ind=0)))) Then
            Begin
              AddBitMap; // добавляю картинку в массив
              If (Index<11) Then
                Index:=Index+1;
              ActionUndo.Enabled:=True; // включаю действие "Отмена"
              If (UndInd<10) Then UndInd:=UndInd+1; // пересчитываю индекс элемента массива
              ActionSave.Enabled:=True; // включаю действие "Сохранить"
              Saved:=False;
            End;

        end;

        // обработчик действия "Отмена"
        procedure TGraphEditorForm.ActionUndoExecute(Sender: TObject);
        begin
          If (UndInd>0) Then
            Begin
              If (ActionReturn.Enabled) Then
                UndInd:=UndInd-1 // уменьшаю индекс элемента массива
              Else
                UndInd:=UndInd-2; 
      // загружаю на канву Image картинку из массива
              ImagePicture.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0, 0, ImagePicture.Width,
                ImagePicture.Height), BitMas[UndInd].Canvas,
                Rect(0, 0, BitMas[UndInd].Width, BitMas[UndInd].Height)); 
            End;
          If (UndInd=0) Then ActionUndo.Enabled:=False; // выключаю действие "Отмена", 
// если дошли до первого элемента массива
          If (UndInd<Index) Then ActionReturn.Enabled:=True // включаю действие   //"Вернуть", если текущий индекс меньше максимального,
          Else ActionReturn.Enabled:=False; // иначе - отключаю
        end;

        // обработчик действия "Вернуть"
        procedure TGraphEditorForm.ActionReturnExecute(Sender: TObject);
        begin
          If (UndInd In [0..9]) Then // если элементы массива не исчерпаны, то
            Begin
              UndInd:=UndInd+1; // увеличиваю индекс
              ImagePicture.Canvas.CopyRect(Rect(0, 0, ImagePicture.Width,
                ImagePicture.Height), BitMas[UndInd].Canvas,
                Rect(0, 0, BitMas[UndInd].Width, BitMas[UndInd].Height));
            End;
    // дальше всё почти также, как и в предыдущем обработчике
          If (UndInd>0) Then ActionUndo.Enabled:=True;
          If (UndInd<Index-1) Then ActionReturn.Enabled:=True
          Else ActionReturn.Enabled:=False;
        end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего во временные файлы сохранять. Даже если электричество скакнёт - потом в теории можно будет восстановить, что удобно.

Только не забудьте удалять свои файлы, замусоревать временную директорию дурной тон.

В памяти можно, конечно держать, но сейчас иногда фотографии весьма много весят...

Comment: ну все изменения и не нужно держать, на практике с головой хватит массива из 10 битмапов. Больше откатов на практике не нужно.
а с файлами мало того что нужно будет проверять уникальность имени файла , так и скорость работы будет страдать.

Comment: Если, например, фото с 20 мегапиксельной камеры, то 10 битмапов будут весить порядка 800 мегабайт. Не смертельно, но всё же многовато на мой взгляд.
В любом случае, решать автору вопроса, он лучше знает как и для чего будет использоваться его редактор.

Comment: ну и с диска подгружать фото с 20 мегапиксельной камеры будут тормоза.

а вообще наверное правильно будет сохранять только изменения.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - иметь массив **`TBitMap`** и все изменения держать в новом битмапе. Соответственно, каждое `UNDO` - это откат на предыдущий битмап.

По коду - это простыня получится.

Answer (score -1):

Добрый день!

Наверное, лучше реализовать при помощи стека. Так можно будет не 5 и не 6 откатов сделать. Вот, кстати, ссылочка на материал. Там как раз про `Undo` через стек: [Back/Forward и Undo/Redo в .NET-приложениях](http://rsdn.ru/article/dotnet/backforward.xml).